# Redis - is there a blpush

Tags: redis

For data communication across processes, I intend to use Redis list.  The producer pushes to the list, while a set of consumers consume the list contents using BRPOP.

In order to restrict the list growing infinitely in size, I want to restrict the list size to a fixed value (say 10K items).  I was surprised to find no equivalent command like BLPUSH or BRPUSH.  Is this a deliberately omitted by Redis folks?

So, I assume I have to create a Txn with Watch/multi to check the list size before pushing.  Is this the right way, or any better techniques available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a lua script for this functionality.

LUA that accepts one key (list name), and two arguments, `new_element_name` and `max_size`.
Return value could be the `LPUSH` return value or `-1` when the list is full.
Here's a script that does this:

```
if tonumber(ARGV[2]) > redis.call('LLEN', KEYS[1]) then
    return redis.call('LPUSH', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])  end 
return -1
```

You should load it once with SCRIPT LOAD:

```
cat blpush.lua | redis-cli -x script load
```

And use it with EVALSHA

```
evalsha 96d1fb35d6173758facda9dbc108296fd4a1512d 1 <myList> <new_element_name> <max_size>
```