# Implement a push/pull (or queue) with redis in Python

Tags: python, redis, queue, message-queue

I'm currently working on a project where I have a lot of tasks that can be parallelized. I'm using redis to store data, and I'd also like to use to handle my jobs queue to.

At first, I've used the [PubSub pattern](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#publish--subscribe) described in Redis doc. The issue here is that it sends every message to every worker where I'd like one message per worker. I have, for the moment, circumvented the problem by adding status (in a DB) for each of the messages but that's clearly not optimal.

Is there a way to easily replace this pubsub pattern with a suitable pattern ?

Comment: A few useful references to this question: (implementation details for implementing queue blocking) https://stackoverflow.com/a/76057700/4790871 (existing implementation of job queues over redis) https://python-rq.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure it that's the most efficient way of implementing a queue with redis but it's definitely a simple way of doing it!

```py
import time
from redis import Redis

REDIS_CLIENT = Redis()

def push(*values):
    REDIS_CLIENT.rpush('QUEUE', *values)

def pull():
    while True:
        msg = REDIS_CLIENT.rpop('QUEUE')
        if msg is None:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue

        work(msg)
```